# Why can't my socket programs connect to the internet?

Tags: sockets, networking

I have begun my first course on networking this semester.
My problem is that whenever I try to connect my socket to a host outside my LAN,
network unreachable error is returned. Whether they be BSD sockets or Java sockets.
Moreover, my nmap probes also return the same error.
Once I asked a similar question here about ping probes and the answer was that my LAN proxy is rejecting ICMP requests. But there are no ICMP requests in establishing TCP connections  right?
Why, on the other hand, my browser can connect to any host... although that it uses the same proxy...
Also,(please pardon me for this long doubt) when I give host name as www.google.com in my sockets, "unknown host" is returned. But my browser happily recognizes the same host.

Thank you in advance...

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

class Whois {
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
    int c;
    Socket s=new Socket(args[0],Integer.parseInt((args[1])));
    InputStream in=s.getInputStream();

    while( (c=in.read()) != -1) {
        System.out.print((char) c);
    }
    s.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Browser operates on port 80 which is passed through; while my guess is your socket is operating on a port which is being blocked.

Comment: I tried port 80 too. same error

Comment: You'll probably need to post up some code as it could be any number of things.

Comment: Put the code into the question itself. It's not readable in the comments.

Comment: Bear with me. I am kind of new to programming forums...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there may be many reasons for this behavior.

My best shot is that you're behind a firewall that's blocking any connections that are not going to port 80. In this case, you may try to connect with your program to the same network, but port 80.

Not sure why you wouldn't get name resolution for google. I'm guessing it's a bug in your code, but can't tell for sure.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried port 80... same error. I copied the Whois program from The Complete Reference, no chance of a bug. Kindly explain

Answer (score 1):

Investigate and understand your network setup. How are you connected to the internet? Your workstation probably has a [default route](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing) pointing to some machine again probably doing [Network Address Translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) (NAT) and/or running a [firewall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_%28computing%29) and maybe that [proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) server. Find out how you do [name resolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) (DNS). One you figure these out you might find what you need to do to connect outside.

On the other hand, errors in the code we don't see in the question are also likely :)

Comment: Yes, its behind a firewall. But my main doubt is that why my browser has no problem establishing TCP connections. I tried port 80, same error is returned

Comment: Does your browser has *proxy* setup? What kind?

Comment: Yes the browser is connected through proxy. It is the same as the system proxy settings.

Comment: Then the browser talks to the proxy locally, and the proxy connects to the real site. There are ways to use that, but it's not relevant to beginner socket programming. Just run both client and the server on the local box, connect to `127.0.0.1`, which is the *loopback interface*.

Comment: So it can be done... thank you so much for the responses. I think I understand it. The browser issues requests to the proxy in a way that is allowed. My programs's requests are blocked.

Answer (score 1):

There is likely a firewall that is blocking all connections to outside hosts, and an internal DNS server that does not lookup external hostnames.  THis is why your socket programs can neither lookup outside hostnames nor connect to outside services.

The same restriction applies to your browser; it's just that your browser is set up to use a proxy server.  This means that the browser isn't directly looking up outside hostnames or connecting to outside hosts - it is only looking up the proxy name and making TCP connections to the proxy server.  The proxy then is doing the hostname lookups and making the TCP connections to the outside world, on behalf of your browser.